# Kafka Streams application strange behavior in docker container

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running Kafka Streams application in a docker container with docker-compose. However, the streams application is behaving strangely. So, I have a source topic (`topicSource`) and multiple destination topics (`topicDestination1` , `topicDestination2` ... `topicDestination10`) that I am branching to based on certain predicates.

`topicSoure` and `topicDestination1` have a direct mapping i.e all the records are simply going into the destination topic without any filtering.

Now all this works perfectly fine when I am run the application locally or on a server without containers.

On the other hand, when I run streams app in container (using docker-compose and using kubernetes) then it doesn't forward all logs from `topicSoure` to `topicDestination1`. In fact, only a few number of records are forwarded. For Example some 3000 + records on source topic and only 6 records in destination topic. And all this is really strange.

**This is my Dockerfile:**

```
#FROM openjdk:8u151-jdk-alpine3.7
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

COPY /target/streams-examples-0.1.jar /streamsApp/

COPY /target/libs /streamsApp/libs

COPY log4j.properties /

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/streamsApp/streams-examples-0.1.jar"]
```

**NOTE:** I am building a jar before creating the image so that I always have an updated code. I have made sure that both the codes, the one running without container and the one with container are same.

**Main.java:**

Creating Source Stream from Source Topic:

```
KStream<String, String> source_stream = builder.stream("topicSource");
```

Branching based on predicates:

```
KStream<String, String>[] branches_source_topic = source_stream.branch(
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"SharingSet") && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File")),        // Sharing Set by Date
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"AddedToSecureLink") && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File")), // Added to secure link
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"AddedToGroup")),                                             // Added to group
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"Add member to role.") || value.contains("Operation\":\"Remove member from role.")),//Role update by date
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"FileUploaded") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileDeleted")
                        || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileRenamed") || value.contains("Operation\":\"FileMoved")),       // Upload file by date
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"UserLoggedIn")),                                             // User logged in by date
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"Delete user.") || value.contains("Operation\":\"Add user.")
                        && value.contains("ResultStatus\":\"success")),                                                     // Manage user by date
                (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"DLPRuleMatch") && value.contains("Workload\":\"OneDrive"))   // MS DLP
                );
```

Sending logs to destination topics:

*This is the direct mapping topic i.e. all the records are simply going into the destination topic without any filtering.*

```
AppUtil.pushToTopic(source_stream, Constant.USER_ACTIVITY_BY_DATE, "topicDestination1");
```

Sending logs from branches to destination topics:

```
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[0], Constant.SHARING_SET_BY_DATE, "topicDestination2");
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[1], Constant.ADDED_TO_SECURE_LINK_BY_DATE, "topicDestination3");
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[2], Constant.ADDED_TO_GROUP_BY_DATE, "topicDestination4");
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[3], Constant.ROLE_UPDATE_BY_DATE, "topicDestination5");
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[4], Constant.UPLOAD_FILE_BY_DATE, "topicDestination6");
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[5], Constant.USER_LOGGED_IN_BY_DATE, "topicDestination7");
AppUtil.pushToTopic(branches_source_topic[6], Constant.MANAGE_USER_BY_DATE, "topicDestination8");
```

**AppUtli.java:**

```
public static void pushToTopic(KStream<String, String> sourceTopic, HashMap<String, String> hmap, String destTopicName) {
    sourceTopic.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
            ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject received = processJSON(new JSONObject(value), destTopicName);

                boolean valid_json = true;
                for(String key: hmap.keySet()) {
                    if (received.has(hmap.get(key))) {
                        send.put(key, received.get(hmap.get(key)));
                    }
                    else {
                        valid_json = false;
                    }
                }   
                if (valid_json) {
                    keywords.add(send.toString());  
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return keywords;
        }
    }).to(destTopicName);
}
```

**Where are the logs coming from:**

So the logs are coming from an online continuous stream. A python job gets the logs which are basically URLs and sends them to a `pre-source-topic`. Then in streams app I am creating a streams from that topic and hitting those URLs which then return json logs that I am pushing to `topicSource`.

I have spent a lot of time trying to resolve this. I have no idea what is going wrong or why is it not processing all logs. Kindly help me figure this out.

Comment: The only idea I have atm is, that you `flatMapValues()` could drop data if it throws an exception... Do you capture `stderr` and `stdout` and verified that data is valid and `flatMapValues()` does not drop anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging I came to know that I was exploring in the wrong direction, it was a simple case of consumer being slow than the producer. The producer kept on writing new records on topic and since the messages were being consumed after stream processing the consumer obviously was slow. Simply increasing topic partitions and launching multiple application instances with the same application id did the trick.